# jQuery .parent().parent() issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I am new to jQuery and I am attempting to change things of divs which are 2 levels about the function trigger:

Here is my first try: *I attempt to find the closest '.node' which is the parent of all of the other divs and edit the children divs.*

```
<script>
function details() {
    $node = $(this).closest( ".node" );
    $node.find( ".content.right .user" ).show();
    $node.find( ".options" ).show();
    $node.find( ".details" ).hide();
}
</script>
```

As that **didn't** work, I then attempted something like:

```
<script>
function details() {
    $node = $(this).parent( ".details" ).parent( ".node" );
    $node.find( ".content.right .user" ).show();
    $node.find( ".options" ).show();
    $node.find( ".details" ).hide();
}
</script>
```

But this didn't work either, so now I am lost.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="node">
    <div class="avatar left" style="background-image:url(assets/default_avatar.png);"></div>
    <div class="content right">
        <div class="user">Foo <a href="./">~Foo_bat</a></div>
    Integer quis ante iaculis, mollis nibh fermentum, vestibulum massa. Quisque et erat et dolor sagittis posuere eu ac risus. Vestibulum a varius turpis. Nunc tincidunt ipsum at tellus volutpat vestibulum. Nulla elementum neque a lectus ullamcorper, eu amet.</div>
    <div class="options">
        <a class="left" href="./reply">Reply</a>
        <a class="left" href="./repost">Repost</a>
        <a class="right" href="./report">Report</a>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <a class="right" href="#" onclick="details()">Details</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know why this might not be working? It's probably something really easy to see, but I can't pick it out...

Comment: `<a class="right" href="#" onclick="details(this)">` and `function details(obj) { $node = $(obj)`

Comment: Do you need to have the inline click handler? if so then you need to pass `this` to `details`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the objject to that function. Because in your current method, `this` refers to window object.

```
<a class="right" href="#" onclick="details(this)">Details</a>
```

Then you can use `.closest()` instead of `parent().parent()`

```
function details(obj) {
    $node = $(obj).closest( ".node" );
    $node.find( ".content.right .user" ).show();
    $node.find( ".options" ).show();
    $node.find( ".details" ).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are anyways using jQuery, I would suggest you use jQuery `click` handler and not inline click.

```
function details(el) {

    $node = $(el).closest( ".node" );
    $node.find( ".content.right .user" ).show();
    $node.find( ".options" ).show();
    $node.find( ".details" ).hide();
}

$('.details a.right').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    details(this)
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sk993/)**

Comment: This is better answer for me, yet if we are hiding any elem then that should be the first line in any function before showing anything else _(i would say it is my approach of doing things, nonetheless i liked it better.)_.

Comment: @Jai you are right with the `hide`, but I noticed that OP is hiding the element which is being clicked. So kept it that way. Was not sure about the actual working of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should try other jQuery selector for above tag  ["parents"](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
you this selector has argument that help you lot.
for you case to get ".node" tag you can use :
{$(this).parents('.node')}

Answer (score 0):

why cant you just access the element itself, with a correct jquery selector, something like..

```
$(".node .options").hide()
```

I have taken Shaunak D example and modded it:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sk993/1/
```